# How to solve problem when reading from a file in c++

Tags: c++, fstream, readfile, ifstream

I'm trying to read the information from a .txt file but something very strange is happening.

Here's the code:

```
ifstream fichier(dir);
fichier.open(dir);
     
if (fichier.is_open())
    cout << "file is opened";

double a;
fichier >> a;
```

I can see on the screen the sentence "file is opened" but nothing is assigned to "a".
The file is not empty, I already verified that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `ifstream fichier(dir);`

In this statement, you are passing the filename to the constructor, so it opens the file immediately.

> `fichier.open(dir);`

And then, in this statement, you are passing the filename to `open()`, so it tries to open the same file *again* and fails, putting the stream into an error state which you are not clearing.  That is why `fichier >> a` does not read anything afterwards.

A file stream can't have two file handles open at the same time.  If it already has a file open, you need to `close()` it before you can open another file with it.

The simplest solution is to just not open the stream twice to begin with.  Either:

- change `ifstream fichier(dir);` to `ifstream fichier;`

```
//ifstream fichier(dir);
ifstream fichier;
fichier.open(dir);
```

- remove `fichier.open(dir);` after `ifstream fichier(dir);`

```
ifstream fichier(dir);
//fichier.open(dir);
```